# Can't run my springboot project on Ubuntu

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, ubuntu

So , I'm currently working on a springboot project and when I try to run mvn spring-boot:run In my Windows/Mac machine it works just fine , the weird thing is when I try to compile and run the same project in my ubuntu cloud server it gets stuck forever with no error message.
I tried to run a jar from other simple projects and it works in the ubuntu server.

The java version is

```
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This is the output from the mvn spring-boot:run on the ubuntu server

````
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.apala:services >-------------------------
[INFO] Building services 0.1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ services >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ services ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ services ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ services ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/apala/apala/services/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ services ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ services <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ services ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
2020-12-30 15:55:16.864  INFO 189642 --- [  restartedMain] com.apala.services.ServicesApplication   : Starting ServicesApplication on apala-cloud-test with PID 189642 (/home/apala/apala/services/target/classes started by root in /home/apala/apala/services)
2020-12-30 15:55:16.867  INFO 189642 --- [  restartedMain] com.apala.services.ServicesApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-30 15:55:18.016  INFO 189642 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-30 15:55:18.016  INFO 189642 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2020-12-30 15:55:18.072  INFO 189642 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-30 15:55:18.284  INFO 189642 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-12-30 15:55:18.509  INFO 189642 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.```
````

Does this has anything to due with any dependency I have that has no compatibility with ubuntu?

Comment: do you run witha n active profile other than "default" in windows?

Comment: This the output from my Mac machine 
``` 2020-12-30 16:39:33.138  INFO 33745 --- [  restartedMain] com.apala.services.ServicesApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default```

Comment: Set the logging level to `TRACE`, and run again, and paste the results. You will see much more details of what is happening.

Comment: I added 
logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
logging.level.com.baeldung.testloglevel=TRACE
logging.level.root=TRACE
Still no clue about whats happening